# Closing the StreamReader

Tags: c#

Is there any Using.System command or anything else, to close the automatically StreamReader.

I've been closing the StreamReader like this e.g.:

```
sr.Close();
```

Comment: Do you mean `using(var sr = GetMyStreamReader()){ /* ... */}`?

Comment: In any case, if this is .NET, if a class implements IDisposable, always create it in a `using` block: `using (var x = new StreamReader(param)) { ... }`. That takes care of closing it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

Answer (score 3):

If you implement a using statement the streamreader will be disposed automatically.

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
{
  allFileText = r.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Since OP is so new, it might be worth mentioning that "dispose" can be presumed to include `Close()`. I recently spotted some old production code where a relatively experienced developer, years ago, assumed otherwise.